# Viewing an object produced by `glm` as a list in R

Tags: r, glm

In R, the regression function `glm` produces an object of class `glm` which is a list.

As it is a list, I should be able to view an object of class `glm` as list without any formatting going on. However, `as.list` doesn't seem to do this.

For example, if `fit` is a model fitted by the function `glm`:

```
> as.list(fit)

Call:  glm(formula = V4 ~ V3 + V2 + V1, family = Gamma, data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           V3           V2           V1  
      1.349        1.593        1.577        1.127  

Degrees of Freedom: 9999 Total (i.e. Null);  9996 Residual
Null Deviance:      2137 
Residual Deviance: 2048         AIC: -30180
```

On the other hand, other functions that apply to list work correctly, such as `names` which will produce the 30 names of the associated list.

Also, I can view individual elements in the same manner that I would for any other list:

```
> fit$coefficients
(Intercept)          V3          V2          V1 
   1.349282    1.593067    1.576868    1.127067
```

Is there any pre-existing function that will allow me to view `fit` in its list form without formatting?

As I said above, I could build my own function using the names of the list, but that seems unnecessary for such a simple task.

Comment: Try `unclass(fit)`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien this comment should be an answer :)

Comment: I agree. I knew there was something basic, but I don't have a lot of experience with classes in R.

Comment: @dickoa -- But it's only 18 characters, and I was being lazy! I will flesh it out a tiny bit and post it, though.

Comment: `str(fit)` looks a sa promising candidate, but I can't get its code :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although `fit` **is** a list, it has class `glm`, so auto-printing it dispatches the `print.glm()` print method. As shown below, `as.list()` preserves the object's class, so doesn't help you at all.

```
fit <- glm(speed~dist, data=cars)  ## A silly example
class(fit)
# [1] "glm" "lm" 
class(as.list(fit))
# [1] "glm" "lm" 
exists("print.glm")
# [1] TRUE
```

Either of the following will print `fit` as a list.

```
unclass(fit)        ## Returns and immediately auto-prints object of class "list"
                    ## using print.default() 

print.default(fit)  ## Bypasses method dispatch, directly calling desired print
                    ## method
```